# UITableView cells are unloaded too early after reordering

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've recently built in reordering into my UITableView but there's a nasty bug I'm experiencing after reordering the cells. The bug only occurs after a cell has been reordered: When scrolling the table view up, the cells visible at the bottom of the screen sometimes simply disappear while scrolling. It seems as if the cells are unloaded too early. This only happens when scrolling up. When scrolling down the bug doesn't exist. The cells that randomly disappear also re-appear when scrolling down once their empty space leaves the screen. Here's a screenshot of this issue:

[image: Cells randomly disappear]

I'm pretty sure that my data source isn't the problem because:

1. When reordering a cell my data source updates as well
2. I've checked the table view with Spark Inspector and the missing cells aren't simply hidden or empty but they just don't exist, there is no cell at all where the empty spaces are.
3. After scrolling around the cells re-appear, the cells randomly appear and disappear

It must be some bug or issue in UITableView, but I may also be wrong with that assumption. Maybe somebody has already faced this problem and can help me out now ;) I'm waiting for your answers :)

**Edit:**
I just checked the -`tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method and the cells are really unloaded normally and that method is called, even though the cells are still visible on the screen!

**Edit (2):**
I now know that the issue only occurs when my table view has a header view. It doesn't matter if I use the default header or a custom one, but whenever I use a header view I also get the bug. When I don't use a header it works just fine. Thats really strange

Note: I'm testing this on iOS 6.1.2

Comment: Have you checked what's going on in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Timothy Moose the data source itself isn't the problem. The cells are unloaded too early, thats the problem. Check out the edit that I added to my question

Comment: they should be recreated in cellforrowat indexpath if they are null, could we see the cellforrowatindexpath code?

Comment: Sounds like your table view's mapping between indexPaths and cells doesn't get updated when the move happens. So when the cell's previous position goes off screen, it gets removed (while still on screen). If I had to guess, I'd say you're doing something unusual in `targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath` that puts the table in a bad state. Can you post that method?

Comment: @Timothy Moose yep, however, even If I don't reorder the cells at all and I only "lift" up a cell, then drop it on the same index path without moving it the tableview starts to mess up. The table view seems to unload the cell above the cell that should actually be unloaded. I'll try removing the `targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath` and then I'll post my implementation of that method.

Comment: Ok, so the issue only appears when using a header view in my table view. When I set the header height to 0 it works just fine, If i use the default header or a custom one the bug seems to appear again. Thats really strange